# Python game not working(shop only showing up once)

Tags: python, debugging, python-2.7

I'm trying to make just a simple text game before I go on learning more things, the first part went good, then I tried to add a shop and when the code is run the shop can only be entered once. Here is the code

```
money = 100
entertainment = 30
rest = 15
social = 30
inv = 1
food = 30
score = 1

def commands():
    print "Commands:"
    print " 'P' Print commands options"
    print " 'S' Go to the shop"
    print "Job list? "
    print " 'M' Market"
    print " 'F' Farm"
    print " 'H' Stay at home a rest"
    print " 'E' Entertainment/go to fair"
def shop():
    print "Shop:"
    print " This is the shop, you buy things with your money that you gain"
    print "Press 'I' for a potato! This gives you 20 extra Inventory points! Costs 80 money!"
    print "Press 'R' for a better bed! This gives you 20 extra rest points! Costs 80 money!"
    print "Press 'S' for a texting plan! This gives you 20 extra social points! Costs 80 money!"
    print "Press 'E' for a better tv! This gives you 20 extra entertainment points! Costs 80 money!"
    print "Press 'H' for this list again!"
    print "Press 'L' to return to your game!"
import random
import sys
commands()
def do_farm():
    entertainment = entertainment - random.randrange(1,7+1)
    rest = rest - random.randrange(1,7+1)
    social = social - random.randrange(1,10+1)
    food = food + random.randrange(1,7+1)
    inv = inv + random.randrange(1,30+1)
    money = money - random.randrange(1,10+1)
    score = score + 1
    print "Money = %d, Entertainment = %d, Rest = %d, Social = %d, Inventory %d, Food %d, Score %d" % (money, entertainment, rest, social, inv, food, score)
    if money <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif food <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif social <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif entertainment <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif rest <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
def do_home():
    entertainment = entertainment + random.randrange(1,3+1)
    rest = rest + random.randrange(1,7+1)
    social = social + random.randrange(1,5+1)
    food = food - 5
    money = money - random.randrange(1,10+1)
    score = score + 1
    print "Money = %d, Entertainment = %d, Rest = %d, Social = %d, Inventory %d, Food %d, Score %d" % (money, entertainment, rest, social, inv, food, score)
    if money <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif food <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif social <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif entertainment <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif rest <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
def do_ent():
    entertainment = entertainment + random.randrange(1,7+1)
    social = social + random.randrange(1,5+1)
    food = food - 3
    money = money - random.randrange(1,10+1)
    score = score + 1
    print "Money = %d, Entertainment = %d, Rest = %d, Social = %d, Inventory %d, Food %d, Score %d" % (money, entertainment, rest, social, inv, food, score)
    if money <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif food <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif social <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif entertainment <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif rest <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
def do_market():
    entertainment = entertainment - random.randrange(1,7+1)
    rest = rest - random.randrange(1,7+1)
    social = social + random.randrange(1,5+1)
    food = food - 5
    money = (inv * 1.5) + money
    inv = 1
    score = score + 1
    print "Money = %d, Entertainment = %d, Rest = %d, Social = %d, Inventory %d, Food %d, Score %d" % (money, entertainment, rest, social, inv, food, score)
    if money <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif food <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif social <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif entertainment <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
    elif rest <= 0:
            print "Game over, Score: %d" % (score)
            exit()
def do_shop_inventory():
    score = score + 10
    inv = inv + 20
    money = money - 80
def do_shop_rest():
    score = score + 10
    rest = rest + 20
    money = money - 80
def do_shop_social():
    score = score + 10
    social = social + 20
    money = money - 80
def do_shop_ent():
    score = score + 10
    entertainment = entertainment + 20
    money = money - 80
def shop_commands():
    while True:
        shop()
        shop_choice = raw_input("Shop command: ")
        if shop_choice == "I":
            do_shop_inventory()
        elif shop_choice == "R":
            do_shop_rest()
        elif shop_choice == "S":
            do_shop_social()
        elif shop_choice == "E":
            do_shop_ent()
        elif shop_choice == "H":
            shop()
        elif shop_choice == "L":
            break
choice = raw_input("Your command: ")
while choice != "Q":
    if choice == "F":
        do_farm()
    elif choice == "H":
        do_home()
    elif choice == "E":
        do_ent()
    elif choice == "M":
        do_market()
    elif choice == "S":
        shop_commands()
    commands()
    choice = raw_input("Your command: ")
```

I am fairly new with Python, about 2-4 weeks. So please no complex answers if possible:D

I would like to know what is wrong and an idea of how to fix it.
Thanks:D
P.S. if you want to suggest an idea that could be added you could do that to!
EDIT: 
Changed code, new error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ImGone\Desktop\MoneySurvival_bakcup.py", line 173, in <module>
    do_farm()
  File "C:\Users\ImGone\Desktop\MoneySurvival_bakcup.py", line 46, in do_farm
    entertainment = entertainment - random.randrange(1,7+1)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'entertainment' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: That's quite a large control flow. Have you been able to isolate the section of your code that's causing problems?

Comment: Not the problem you're trying to solve, but… the first time through, you set `choice` and `shop_choice` to lowercase `"p"`, which will not match `choice == "P"`. (And likewise, if the user types a lowercase `p` it won't match next time through.) You probably want all those checks to be `choice.upper() == "P"` and the like—or, even better, replace the `choice = raw_input(…)` with `choice = raw_input(…).upper()`.

Comment: Btw: constructing large switches (elif statements) like you did is considered a bad programming practice. Try at least to consolidate your conditions (you check different conditions but they all lead to same print and exit) into one if. Here you can read more: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SwitchStatementsSmell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the problem Amber found, you've got some indentation problems that will make it hard to get to the store.

The `shop == "P"` check is inside the `rest <= 0` case inside the `choice == "F"` case. So, the only way to get to the shop is to go to the farm and use up all your rest. That can't be right.

This would be a lot simpler if you factored out your code into functions, like this:

```
def do_farm():
    entertainment = entertainment - random.randrange(1,7+1)
    # ...
```

And then your main loop could just do this:

```
if choice == "F":
    do_farm()
elif choice == "S":
    do_shop()
# ...
```

Also, it's a lot easier to get the loop right if you do things the other way around, asking for the choice at the top of the loop instead of the bottom. For example:

```
def shop():
    while True:
        shop()
        shop_choice = raw_input("Shop command: ")
        if shop_choice == "I":
            do_shop_inventory()
        elif shop_choice == "R":
            # ...
        elif shop_choice == "L":
            break
```

It is a bit annoying that you have to do a `while True` and a `break` instead of putting the condition directly in the loop, but the alternative is to write the same input code twice (once before the loop, and once again at the end) instead of once (at the top of the loop), or write convoluted code that can handle a "no input yet" state.

Comment: I'm going to do that, didn't think about it at first thanks(:

Comment: @ImGone98: If you mean the last part… I'm guessing you didn't want to have to do `while True` and `break`, and thought "there must be a better way"… but unfortunately, without severely restructuring your code, there isn't a better way.

Comment: I added all that but it now gives me that error?

Comment: @ImGone98: The problem is that you're trying to use global variables, but not declaring them `global`. Sometimes Python can guess that they're global, but when it can't, you get an `UnboundLocalError`. You can fix it by adding `global entertainment` to the top of the function body. A _better_ fix is to reorganize your code to not need globals. For example, if you created a class, with all of these values as instance variables, and all of these functions as methods, they could do `self.entertainment`, etc. But this is way too much to explain in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

You never clear out `shop_choice`, so the next time someone tries to go to the shop, they instantly leave it (because `shop_choice` is already set to `L` from the previous time they visited and then left the shop).

Comment: So how do I clear it out?

Comment: @ImGone98: The problem is that you're checking the value _before_ you call `raw_input`, so it has whatever value you happened to leave there. A better way to do it is to move the `raw_input` to the top of the loop. This is hard to explain without code, so I put it into an answer (even though it's really supplemental to Amber's answer, not a replacement).